# Minimal Triangles

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, number-theory

Make an upside down triangle of **positive** integers. Every number in the triangle must be **distinct**. Each number is the **summation** of its two parents (similar to how Pascal's triangle is constructed, but upside-down). Construct it in such a way that the bottom number is **minimized**.

For example, for input `n = 4`, here is a possible solution:

```
4  1  2  7
 5  3  9
  8  12
   20
```

A reversal of the top numbers, such as `7 2 1 4`, would also work.

For input `n = 5`, here is a possible solution:

```
7  2  1  4  6
  9  3  5 10
   12  8 15
     20 23
       43
```

The solution for `n = 2` is rather boring:

```
1 2
 3
```

The sequence of bottom numbers is described in [OEIS A028307](http://oeis.org/A028307).

#### Challenge

Given an input integer `n > 0` describing how many elements are in the first row, output the corresponding minimal triangle as explained above. Output can be as ASCII-art of the triangle, a list-of-lists or matrix, to STDOUT as one row per line, etc.

### Rules

- If applicable, you can assume that the input/output will fit in your language's native Integer type.
- The input and output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Is padding between numbers specified?

Comment: @DeadPossum Up to you, so long as it's unambiguous (e.g., don't use `1` as your padding). The I/O isn't the interesting part of this challenge.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 bytes

```
!*ṗµ+ƝÐĿ€FQƑ$Ðf-ị$ÞḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9qZWxsef//ISrhuZfCtSvGncOQxL/igqxGUcaRJMOQZi3hu4skw57huKL///8y)

It's trivial to prove that there exists a solution which all elements on the first row are in range `[1,n!n]`.

Be careful as this computes an array of 10'077'696 3-element arrays for `n=3`.

---

Proof:

Let `x` be on the `k`th layer (`1 ≤ k ≤ n`, and there are `a` numbers to the left of `x`. Let `b0, b1, ..., bn-1` be the numbers on the first line.

Then:

`x = ba × (k-1 choose 0) + ba+1 × (k-1 choose 1) + ... + ba+k-1 × (k-1 choose k-1)`

It can be proven that all of the coefficients are non-negative and less than `n!` (except when `n=1`, in that case the algorithm gives correct result anyway), and two different numbers have two different set of coefficients.

So if the first line are chosen to be the powers of `n!` with exponent `0,1,2,...,n-1`, the value of each cell uniquely determines the set of coefficients, and thus is unique.

---

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 bytes

```
!*r1œcµ_ƝÐĿ€FQƑ$ÐfṪ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9qZWxsef//ISpyMcWTY8K1X8adw5DEv@KCrEZRxpEkw5Bm4bmq////Mg)

Output format: Columns, upside down.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>251</s> <s>239</s> 230 bytes

-9 bytes thanks to @Mr.Xcoder

Outputs list of lines of triangle, bottom to top.

```python
def F(s,d):
 if-~d==len(s):
	u=sum(s,[])
	if len(u)==len(set(u)):print s;g
 else:
	for j in range(s[d][0]):
	 s[d+1]=[j]
	 for i in s[d]:j=i-j;s[d+1]+=j,
	 if min(s[d+1])>=0:F(s,d+1)
i,I=1,input()
while i:F(eval(`[[i]]*I`),0);i+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5BC8IwDIXP9lfk2LgKm@BlIx4Ff0MpKKzTlFnHuile/OszVW/v5X3Jy/Carve4XZbWd3DQybRYK@Bu826Jeh91Er@aKc03Ca1DteIOcjDjH/CTaKyHkeMEqbko8H3ystXdRwjAEcZzvHidbOts6fI9EF1UjmxwYjLHmctEHYg3ofkBBQUjgDTeOOrfDPdU1t9PiwoVmyNVhuMwTxrV88q9B5bYP869PlnLzq2PJzQlNlxQtSy7Dw)

Bruteforce-ish solution.
For all i in [1 .. ] generate all possbile triangles starting from the bottom, until one with all different numbers is found.

Comment: Yeah, that output is fine.

Comment: [230 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY5BC8IwDIXP9lfk2LgKm@BlIx4Ff0MpKKzTlFnHuile/OszVW/v5X3Jy/Carve4XZbWd3DQybRYK@Bu826Jeh91Er@aKc03Ca1DteIOcjDjH/CTaKyHkeMEqbko8H3ystXdRwjAEcZzvHidbOts6fI9EF1UjmxwYjLHmctEHYg3ofkBBQUjgDTeOOrfDPdU1t9PiwoVmyNVhuMwTxrV88q9B5bYP869PlnLzq2PJzQlNlxQtSy7Dw)