# Draw a descendant pyramid (addition)

Tags: code-golf

**Challenge**

Given a sequence of non-negative integers, create a function that output a descendant pyramid where the children are the sum of both parent numbers.

The result is outputted as an string using tab `\t`.

*Note: trailing tabs on each line are not required*

```
1\t\t2\t\t3\n\t3\t\t5\t\n\t\t8\t\t results in 
1       2       3
    3       5   
        8
```

Optionally result can be outputted as an array using an empty position as space.

```
[[1,,2,,3],
[,3,,5,],
[,,8,,]]
```

**Example:**

Given `4,5,7,3,4,2` Output:

```
4       5       7       3       4       2
    9       12      10      7       6
        21      22      17      13
            43      39      30
                82      69
                    151
```

**Rules**

- Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply
- Input can be a string using any separator or an array
- Leading/trailing newlines and tabs are permitted (but not required as long as the output is an inverted pyramid)

**Test Cases**

```
Input: 1,3,5

1       3       5
    4       8
        12


Input: 9,8,7,6,5

9       8       7       6       5
    17      15      13      11
        32      28      24
            60      52
                112


Input: 5,5,2,5

[[5,,5,,2,,5],
[,10,,7,,7,],
[,,17,,14,,],
[,,,31,,,]]

Input: 3,3,3

[[3,,3,,3],
[,6,,6,],
[,,12,,]]
```

Winning criteria is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

***Note:*** This challenge is very close to [Generate Pascal's triangle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3815/generate-pascals-triangle). The difference is the custom starting sequence (pascal goes from 1 and in ascendant mode, this from an input and in descendant mode).

**[Sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/16586#16586)**

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/163475/42963).

Comment: `non-negative integers` do we have to handle `0`? There are some golfing possibilities if empty spaces are filled with `0`s.

Comment: May we return an array with tabs or empty strings/arrays in the empty positions?

Comment: @Adám Yes. Anything that represents emptiness

Comment: "using an empty position as space" what is an "empty position" here? May these be space characters or negative numbers? I ask since many languages with array-like containers don't have such a concept I believe. EDIT - it seems your answer to Adám probably addresses this.

Comment: @JungHwanMin Unfortunately yes, your function/program must handle `0`

Comment: @JonathanAllan empty position can be an empty space, null, undefined, etc anything but integer

Comment: "Leading/trailing newlines and tabs are permitted" - May we include empty result(s) at the bottom in the array output too?

Comment: @JonathanAllan *trailing newlines and tabs are permitted*

Comment: @Adám question adjusted to be less generic :)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

-1 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

```
vD„		ý'	N×ì,ü+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/zOVRwzxOzsN71Tn9Dk8/vEbn8B7t//@jTXRMdcx1jHVMdIxiAQ)

Comment: That's a lot of spaces... tabs?

Comment: ...or zero spaces and a few tabs :p

Comment: Indeed, those are tabs :)

Comment: `gF` can be `v` for -1.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>14</s>  13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>14 -> 13 assumes trailing spaces-only entry is allowed in the list format output; if not I shall revert to the 14 ([asked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/167797/draw-a-descendant-pyramid-addition#comment405522_167797))</sup>

```
+ƝƬK€z⁶Zṙ"JC$
```

A monadic link. Output is a list of lists using space characters as the spaces (includes a single trailing spaces-only entry).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9qZWxsef//K8adxqxL4oKseuKBtlrhuZkiSkMk/8OHxZLhuZj//zEsMyw1)** (includes a footer to show the list structure since running the monadic link as a full program will print smashed output implicitly.)

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>31</s> 28 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Tacit prefix function. Uses a single space as empty slot marker. Returns list of lists of numbers/spaces.

```apl
⍳∘≢{∊(⍺⍴''),,∘' '¨2+/⍣⍺⊢⍵}¨⊂
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/9fklpc8qhtQvWjvqlACkh6Bfv7KaQpPOrdqvCou0UBKt42ESJWywUUyMwHChn8f9S7@VHHjEedi6ofdXRpPOrd9ah3i7q6po4OUFRdQf3QCiNt/Ue9i0ESXYtAeg@teNTV9D8NZF5vH9AcT/9HXc2H1hsDTQfygoOcgWSIh2cw2FEKhjrGOqZcYKaljoWOuY4ZjGuqY6pjBOMYA5UZAwA)

`⍳∘≢{`…`}¨⊂` apply the below function for each of
`⍳` the **ɩ**ndices `∘` of `≢` the tally with
`⊂` the entire argument:

`⊢⍵` yield the right argument (the original input)

`2+/⍣⍺` apply pairwise sum as many times as indicated by the left argument

`,∘' '¨` append a space to each number

`(`…`),` append that to the following:

`⍺⍴''` left-argument elements of the empty string (padded with spaces)

`∊` **ϵ**nlist (flatten)

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 74 bytes

```
ArrayPad[Riffle[#,],k++,]&/@NestList[k=0;BlockMap[Tr,#,2,1]&,#,Tr[1^#]-1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcfdCoIwFADge59iMJDCE2VQliKsrvuR8m4sOCwPDf9i7iKJnn159fG16F5Vi85o9FcieR87h5801X2rsoDymT9Yi2OBT3kzRE0lOSioowhUuBSXanAnMzhZ56vs2PS6PuNblhY4rCFW4WRpZfzgajHNz7OgsKZzgsR3D2wHLAG2Bbb5@T8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 22 bytes

```
zoΣ~+R"	"oJ"		"msNU¡Ẋ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/vyr/3OI67SAlTqV8LyVOTqXcYr/QQwsf7urS/v//f7SljoWOuY6ZjmksAA)

#### Explanation

```
z(Σ~+R" "(J"  "ms))NU¡Ẋ+  -- example input: [1,2,3]
                     ¡    -- infinitely do and collect in list
                      Ẋ+  -- | sum adjacent
                          -- : [[1,2,3],[3,5],[8],[],[],...
                    U     -- keep up until first repetition: [[1,2,3],[3,5],[8],[]]
z(                )N      -- zip with natural numbers under (example on 1 [1,2,3])
   ~+    (       )        -- | join arguments modified by
     R" "                 -- | | replicate tab: " "
               ms         -- | | show each: ["1","2","3"]
          J"  "           -- | | join with 2 tabs: ["1","  ","2","  ","3"]
                          -- | : [" ","1","  ","2","  ","3"]
  Σ                       -- | concatenate: " 1  2  3"
                          -- : [" 1  2  3","  3  5","   8"]
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 73 bytes

Weird source code ... Anyway, that's [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)!

Includes leading and trailing whitespace.

```javascript
f=(a,p=`
`)=>p+a.join`		`+(1/(y=a.shift())?f(a.map(x=>y+(y=x)),p+`	`):'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclRCsIwDADQ73qRJTRW1IkgZB5EhIS5asdsix2ynb76ft@oXy39J@R5G9NjqNUzKGWWjSB32aobU4hijFjY72BldeUV/AyIVw/q3pph4W61/1oQKVsxgpemwdqnWNI0uCk9wcOtpROd6UgtHe6I9Qc)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>101</s> <s>93</s> 80 bytes

Saved 7 bytes (`map(str,x)` instead of `for in` and init y as `''`) and got rid of the trailing newlines (`x and[` instead of `print(`), thanks to *Jo King*.

Saved 13 bytes (`[*map(sum,zip(x,x[1:]))]` instead of `[x[j]+x[j+1]for j in range(len(x)-1)]`) thanks to *ovs*.

```python
f=lambda x,y='':x and[y+'		'.join(map(str,x))]+f([*map(sum,zip(x,x[1:]))],y+'	')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtLCoMwFEXH7sLZS@pF8FMKgisJDlJEmtLEoBFe3HxMnZ6Pj@Gzui6lZfxp@551yYgj0cCldrOKFRUF1d/VOGG1F3vYwFJO1SLU4waHxWm8YLBqhikr/B@S6dZ@My4gxz2eeKFDjzZHSBc)

Comment: @ovs: Ah, cool. I should have realized I could map the sum. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, 62 bytes

```perl
$,="\t\t";do{say"\t"x$i++,@F;map$_+=$F[++$q[@F]],@F}while$#F--
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19Fx1YppiSmRMk6Jb@6OLESyFGqUMnU1tZxcLPOTSxQide2VXGL1tZWKYx2cIuNBQrXlmdk5qSqKLvp6v7/b6JgqmCuYKxgomD0L7@gJDM/r/i/rq@pnoGhwX/dRAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 35 bytes

```
+¶<`\d+ *(?=(\d+)?)
    $#1*$.(*_$1*)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X/vQNpuEmBRtTi0Ne1sNIEPTXpOLU0XZUEtFT0MrXsVQS5Pz/39DTk4jTk5jAA) Explanation:

```
+
```

Repeat until the buffer stops changing,

```
¶<`
```

Print the contents of the buffer before the substitution, with a trailing newline, and

```
\d+ *(?=(\d+)?)
    $#1*$.(*_$1*)
```

Substitute a single number with a pair of tabs, but a number followed by another number with a tab, the sum, and another tab.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```perl6
{$_,{say "	"x$++~.join("		");$_[1..*]Z+@$_}...0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1olXqe6OLFSQYlTqUJFW7tOLys/M09DiZNTSdNaJT7aUE9PKzZK20ElvlZPT8@g9n@aRrSJjqmOuY6xjomOUazmfwA)

Anonymous code block that takes a list of integers and prints the inverted pyramid.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>112</s> 109 bytes

- -3 from @ceilingcat

```c
j,k;f(*i,c){for(j=c;j;j-=puts("")){for(k=c-j;k--;)putchar(9);for(;++k<j;i[k]+=i[k+1])printf("%d\t\t",i[k]);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5NboMwEEb3nMIiqmRjXIlFm0aDcxHCwjWFjKEQgUMWEVev6ymrbqzxe9/8WGUHM3YhuLyHlmeYW/Fsp5k7bcGBU/p29wtPU7HjXlvloFcKRBT2amZ@EkAGpOxLB1j1tdTxlUUtbjOOvuXpS3PxF5/mJAVsWzjgaId788XKxTc4vV7PyT804CexJLazb4Mjp8LMnc1pJcuyWK@CPRPGsOUkzsX@jSBGVzMsFeEa/hgdSBx1AViSAJRS7DlURa2Nn5AGrRXGE5O9i5PPKa4KQZO2ZAvhFD7CMbyHtx/bDqZbgnr8Ag)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 151 bytes

```
func[b][m: length? b repeat n m[loop n - 1[prin"^-"]print replace/all
form b" ""^-^-"c: copy[]repeat i -1 + length? b[append c b/(i) + b/(i + 1)]b: c]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nU7LCsIwELz3K4aeLFJKLPXRi//gdVkhSRMtpEko9SDit9dUBK8ie5iBmdmZ0XTzyXTEmW1ne/OaFNPQwhl/ma5HKIwmGjnBYyAXQkykhKA49j4/lzkvZFpMTmpTSecyG8YBKkee9OTQLXSId@LPox6lwPpbQDJG4ztoqGrVF0laMIEoWKUs82xJoEbD2bvsUeKne2aWDthjh@1f2QYNNn8l67S25vkF)

### More readable:

```
f: func [ b ] [
    m: length? b
    repeat n m [
        loop n - 1 [ prin tab ]
        print replace/all form b " " rejoin [ tab tab ]
        c: copy []
        repeat i (length? b) - 1 [
            append c b/(i) + b/(i + 1)
        ]
        b: c
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 163 bytes

```cs
b=>{var s="";var c=b.Length;for(int i=0;i<c;i++){for(int z=0;z<i;z++)s+="\t";for(int x=0;x<c-i;x++){s+=b[x]+"\t\t";b[x]=x==c-i-1?0:b[x]+b[x+1];}s+="\n";}return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9BS8QwEIXv/RVDTy1Ny66uCKbZPQieFAQPHmoPaYzdgW0CmexaW/rba1pxGRiG99438BTlitSsTpIIXp1tney6aIwi8tKjgovFT3iRaBLyDk1b1SBdS@kSid5@yOuueDobVaLxVc3gL7UHCWJuxH68SAck4pgvhxJN8axN64/8y7okIIBiw7FUHLMsHf/FIYhDiXwIImUi/vDxFeiD15cqR94vSLCbqq@zkFlSyy16IYKfbw@bh9ULK9vWfFpfmZhPTvuzM0B8mvm1xaM1ZE@6eHfodSITo79hLQXjjt2xe3bLduxmStOATGHmXw)

Readable:

```cs
b =>    {
            var s = "";
            var c = b.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < i; z++)
                    s += "\t";
                for (int x = 0; x < c - i; x++)
                {
                    s += b[x] + "\t\t";
                    b[x] = x == c - i - 1 ? 0 : b[x] + b[x + 1];
                }
                s += "\n";
            }
            return s;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/) `-Rx`, <s>20</s> 18 bytes

The second line includes a trailing tab.

```
Nc¡=ä+
Ëq' ² iEç'
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=TmOhPeQrCstxJwmyIGlF5ycJ&input=WzQsNSw3LDMsNCwyXQotUng=)

---

### Explanation

```
                  :Implicit input of array U
N                 :The array of inputs (NOT the input array)
 c                :Concatenate
  ¡               :  Map U
    ä+            :    Consecutive sums of U
   =              :    Reassign to U for next iteration
\n                :Reassign the resulting 2D-array to U
Ë                 :Map each array at index E
 q                :  Join with
  '\t             :   Tab
     ²            :   Repeated twice
       i          :  Prepend
          '\t     :   Tab
         ç        :   Repeated
        E         :   E times
                  :Implicitly join with newlines, trim (not strictly necessary) and output.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 18 bytes

```
2lṠ)↔ðdvj:ẏ$꘍⁋ð9CV
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIybOG5oCnihpTDsGR2ajrhuo8k6piN4oGLw7A5Q1YiLCIiLCIxLCAyLCAzLCA0Il0=)

I *think* this works? Output format is annoying.

```
   )↔              # Repeat until no change, collecting values
  Ṡ                # Sums of
2l                 # Consecutive pairs
       vj          # Join each by...
     ðd            # Double spaces
           $꘍      # Pad left with spaces by
         :ẏ        # range(0, len(list)
             ⁋     # Join by newlines
                 V # Replace
              ð    # Spaces
               9C  # With tabs
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>79</s> <s>75</s> 70 bytes

Has leading tabs. Prints the required output then prints trailing tabs and newlines forever.

```
def f(x,y='\n'):print(y,*x,sep='        ');f([*map(sum,zip(x,x[1:]))],y+'   ')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNo0Kn0lY9Jk9d06qgKDOvRKNSR6tCpzi1wFadk1Nd0zpNI1orN7FAo7g0V6cqswCovCLa0CpWUzNWp1JbHajif4VttImOqY65jrGOiY5RLBfQSM3/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 67 bytes

A straightforward recursive solution.

```ruby
F=->a,n=0{puts ?\t*n+a*"		"
a[0]&&F[a.each_cons(2).map(&:sum),n+1]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWN53dbHXtEnXybA2qC0pLihXsY0q08rQTtZQ4OZW4EqMNYtXU3KIT9VITkzPik_PzijWMNPVyEws01KyKS3M1dfK0DWNrIUZtcIuONtEx1THXMdYx0TGKjYUIw2wCAA)